# Powershell import-CSV and process batches of 10 with a loop

Tags: powershell, loops, import-csv

I've been working on a script that imports CSV file, then depending on if some values are present, outputs contents in a specific format. Example:

```
#all 4 variations are similar, with the only difference being PasswordLastSet and LastLogonDate either present or not - they are in epoch format, so I compare them to 1, which works fine

$users = import-csv "C:\Users\username\Documents\filename.csv" -delimiter ";"
$body = foreach($_ in $users){
    if($_.'PasswordLastSet' -lt 1){
        
        if($_.'LastLogonDate' -lt 1){
                #last logon and password are empty
'"' +  $_."SamAccountName" + '"' + ':' + '{"DisplayName":' + '"' + $_."DisplayName" + '"' + ',"UserPrincipalName":' + '"' +  $_."UserPrincipalName" + '"' + ',"BusinessCategory":' + '"' + $_."BusinessCategory" + '"' + ',"EmployeeType":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeType" + '"' + ',"LeaveOfAbsence":'  + '"' +  $_."LeaveOfAbsence" + '"' + ',"LineOfBusiness":' + '"' + $_."LineOfBusiness" + '"' + ',"Login":' + '"' + $_."Login".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"MultiFactorAuthentication":' + '"' + $_."2FA" + '"' + ',"DistinguishedName":' + '"' + $_."DistinguishedName".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"EmployeeNumber":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeNumber" + '"' + ',"Enabled":' + '"' + $_."Enabled" + '"' + '},'}
         else{
            #password empty, last logon present
'"' +  $_."SamAccountName" + '"' + ':' + '{"DisplayName":' + '"' + $_."DisplayName" + '"' + ',"UserPrincipalName":' + '"' +  $_."UserPrincipalName" + '"' + ',"BusinessCategory":' + '"' + $_."BusinessCategory" + '"' + ',"EmployeeType":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeType" + '"' + ',"LeaveOfAbsence":'  + '"' +  $_."LeaveOfAbsence" + '"' + ',"LineOfBusiness":' + '"' + $_."LineOfBusiness" + '"' + ',"Login":' + '"' + $_."Login".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"MultiFactorAuthentication":' + '"' + $_."2FA" + '"' + ',"DistinguishedName":' + '"' + $_."DistinguishedName".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"EmployeeNumber":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeNumber" + '"' + ',"LastLogonDate":' + '"' + $_."LastLogonDate" + '"' + ',"Enabled":' + '"' + $_."Enabled" + '"' + '},'}
    }
    else{
        if($_.'LastLogonDate' -lt 1){
            #password present, last logon empty
'"' +  $_."SamAccountName" + '"' + ':' + '{"DisplayName":' + '"' + $_."DisplayName" + '"' + ',"UserPrincipalName":' + '"' +  $_."UserPrincipalName" + '"' + ',"BusinessCategory":' + '"' + $_."BusinessCategory" + '"' + ',"EmployeeType":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeType" + '"' + ',"LeaveOfAbsence":'  + '"' +  $_."LeaveOfAbsence" + '"' + ',"LineOfBusiness":' + '"' + $_."LineOfBusiness" + '"' + ',"Login":' + '"' + $_."Login".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"MultiFactorAuthentication":' + '"' + $_."2FA" + '"' + ',"DistinguishedName":' + '"' + $_."DistinguishedName".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"EmployeeNumber":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeNumber" + '"' + ',"PasswordLastSet":' + '"' + $_."PasswordLastSet" + '"' + ',"Enabled":' + '"' + $_."Enabled" + '"' + '},'}
         else{
            #password and last logon present
'"' +  $_."SamAccountName" + '"' + ':' + '{"DisplayName":' + '"' + $_."DisplayName" + '"' + ',"UserPrincipalName":' + '"' +  $_."UserPrincipalName" + '"' + ',"BusinessCategory":' + '"' + $_."BusinessCategory" + '"' + ',"EmployeeType":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeType" + '"' + ',"LeaveOfAbsence":'  + '"' +  $_."LeaveOfAbsence" + '"' + ',"LineOfBusiness":' + '"' + $_."LineOfBusiness" + '"' + ',"Login":' + '"' + $_."Login".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"MultiFactorAuthentication":' + '"' + $_."2FA" + '"' + ',"DistinguishedName":' + '"' + $_."DistinguishedName".replace('\','\\') + '"' + ',"EmployeeNumber":' + '"' + $_."EmployeeNumber" + '"' + ',"PasswordLastSet":' + '"' + $_."PasswordLastSet" + '"' + ',"LastLogonDate":' + '"' + $_."LastLogonDate" + '"' + ',"Enabled":' + '"' + $_."Enabled" + '"' + '},'}
    }
    } 
$output = "{" + $body
$output = $output.TrimEnd(',') + "}"
$output
$output | Out-File "$env:userprofile\Documents\filename.txt" -append -Encoding UTF8
```

The above code works as I want it to. The issue I have is with creating a loop to process (up to) 10 records from the CSV file.
I want it to go through 10 users, check the conditions and format output accordingly, then add "{", Trim the last comma and add "}", then go through another 10 users, considering that the last loop might have less than 10 users.

I've tried to write the loops myself, but any way I tried, something was wrong and I gave up for a while.

If something is unclear, let me know. Please excuse my unclear formatting.
I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Can you add an example input (csv data) of 2-3 example users and an example of the desired output ? It looks like you're building your own json output ... but it would be much more simpler to manipulate the data first then use `Convertto-Json` to produce exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, I would suggest looking into working with your data and converting it to Json through `Convertto-Json` instead of building your own.

That being said, here is a sample on how you could manage increments of 10 users.

You will need to adapt it to your need but it essentially process batch of 10 users and / or the remaining and allow you to add anything before, within and after the 10 users loop.

**Example**

```
$Users = 1..22
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$batchItemsCount = 10
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Users.Count; $i += $batchItemsCount ) {
    $MaxIndex = $i + $batchItemsCount - 1
    if ($i + $batchItemsCount - 1 -gt $Users.Count ) { $MaxIndex = $Users.Count - 1 }

    if ($i -eq 0) {
        $sb.AppendLine('{') | Out-Null
    } else {
        $sb.AppendLine(',') | Out-Null
        $sb.AppendLine('{') | Out-Null
    }

    
    # Your 10 users
    foreach ($U in $users[$i..$MaxIndex]) {
       # Insert your code here
        $sb.AppendLine(" $U") | Out-Null
        
    }
    $sb.Append('}') | Out-Null
}
$sb.ToString()
```

**Output**

```
{
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
},
{
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
},
{
 21
 22
}
```

Note: I used a stringbuilder object, which is more performant than just manipulating string directly but you can replace the string builder statements by your strings directly if you are not comfortable with it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's what I was looking for!

I tried using `Convertto-Json`, but the output format was not exactly what I needed and this manual conversion seemed to work better.
Thank you once again.